# Jquery increment and decrement for dynamic generated field

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I have simple 
[code](http://jsfiddle.net/maksim/uSzr7/)  to increment and decrement field. everything was fine but i don't know how many field I get ( it's generate by mvc) My question is how to smart bind two buttons for each field on page?
I tried to use  `$(this.id+"x").val(currentVal - 1)` but it's wrong way , I think.

Thanks for any suggestions

Additional:

1. I can't use Jquery Mobile range input.
2. Text box "Text Pin #4" must be allways focused.
3. All buttons must be possible to click on Mobile device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can select elements relative to the one that has the event triggered on it:

```
$(".bplus").click(function() {

    //find the input relative to this element
    $(this).closest('td').prev().children('input').val(function (i, oldValue) {

        //make sure the old value is being interpreted as an integer
        oldValue = parseInt(oldValue, 10);

        //if the old value is a valid integer below 999 then add one,
        //otherwise return 999
        return (oldValue != NaN && oldValue < 999) ? (oldValue + 1) : 999;
    });
});

$(".bminus").click(function() {

    //find the input relative to this element
    $(this).closest('td').next().children('input').val(function (i, oldValue) {

        //make sure the old value is being interpreted as an integer
        oldValue = parseInt(oldValue, 10);

        //if the old value is a valid integer above 0 then subtract one,
        //otherwise return 0
        return (oldValue != NaN && oldValue > 0) ? (oldValue - 1) : 0;
    });
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/uSzr7/16/

Here is some documentation for ya:

- `.closest()`: http://api.jquery.com/closest
- `.prev()`: http://api.jquery.com/prev
- `.children()`: http://api.jquery.com/children
- `.val()`: http://api.jquery.com/val (see the section on passing `.val()` a function)

Another way to handle the validation is to always add or subtract one but then add a `change` event handler to the `input` elements that checks to make sure the value is valid. This helps work with native form controls since you are using the `type="number"` input tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".bplus").click(function(){
    var txtField = $(this).parents('tr').find('input[type="number"]')
    var currentVal = parseInt(txt.val());
    if (currentVal < 999)
        txtField.val((currentVal || 0) + 1);
});
```

I put `(currentVal || 0)`, that means if `currentVal==NaN`, it will be replaced by 0

Comment: firebug error:

`input is not defined

error source line:

var txtField = $(this).parents('tr').find(input[type="number"])`

Comment: please check this link 
http://magentocodes.blogspot.in/2013/11/simple-jquery-increment-decrement-on.html